# Hibernate where or statement does not behave when child property is evaluated

Tags: hibernate, grails

The title speaks the question itself. I have this Grails Domain class.

```
class IonicBond {
    ...

    static hasMany = [
        typeIIs: TypeII,
        typeRs: TypeR,
    ]

    static constraints = {
        typeIIs nullable: true
        typeRs nullable: true
    }
}
```

I need to query instances of `IonicBond` based on it's `hasMany` properties. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<IonicBond> list = IonicBond.createCriteria().list {
    or {
        typeIIs {
            eq("classCode", "WD996")
        }
        typeRs {
            eq("classCode", "WD996")
        }
    }
}
```

I need to do a query something for this statement: *"Get all `IonicBond` where either one of its `TypeII` children or `TypeR` children's `classCode` equals to 'WD996'"*. The problem is that this query will only work if the `IonicBond` instance has both `TypeII` *and* `TypeR` children. It will not include:

1. `IonicBond` with `TypeR` children with `class` value of "WD996" but has no `TypeII` child.
2. `IonicBond` with `TypeII` children with `class` value of "WD996" but has no `TypeR` child.

How can I include this to the result set?

Comment: adding `isNull('typeRs')` in `typeIIs` closure and `isNull('typeIIs')` in `typeRs` closure should do it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `createCriteria()` uses `INNER JOIN` by default, meaning it will really not include `IonicBond` instances that have only `typeIIs` children, or `typeRs`, only both. The solution is to change it to a `LEFT JOIN` using `createAlias()`:

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria

...
    ArrayList<IonicBond> list = IonicBond.createCriteria().list {
        createAlias('typeIIs', 'typeIIs', Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('typeRs', 'typeRs', Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)

        or {
            eq("typeIIs.classCode", "WD996")
            eq("typeRs.classCode", "WD996")
        }
    }
```

> Note that Hibernate will not use `LEFT JOIN` as default join, even if you set all of its child to `constraints.nullable: true`. You must state it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
ArrayList<IonicBond> list = IonicBond.where { typeRs { classCode == "WD996" } || typeIIs { classCode == "WD996" } }.list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Detached Criteria is one way to query the GORM. You first create a DetachedCriteria with the name of the domain class for which you want to execute the query. Then you call the method 'build' with a 'where' query or criteria query.

```
def criteria = new DetachedCriteria(IonicBond).build {

    or {
            typeIIs {
                eq("classCode", "WD996")
            }
            typeRs {
                eq("classCode", "WD996")
            }
        }

}
def result = criteria.list()
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: Yeah, what's with the `build` closure?